# Show that this directed graph is eulerian and hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path, hamiltonicity

Define the directed graph $D_{n,k} = (V_{n,k},A_{n,k})$ for $k \ge 2$.

The vertices are the $k$-dimensional vectors with values between 1 and $n$, that is $V=\{1,..n \}^k$.

Two vertices $u=(u_1,...,u_k)$ and $v=(v_1,...v_k)$ are connected by and edge $(u,v) \in A_{n,k}$, if $u_{i+1}=v_i$ for $i=1,...,(k-1).$

Show that this graph is eulerian and hamiltonian.

I don't understand the structure of this graph. I will try to experiment around with very small examples for k and n and hope that I will be able to 'see' the circles then...thanks for any hint and/or idea..

Comment: I think I understand now that to show the graph being eulerian one can show that the graph is balanced...which is probably not difficult...

Comment: I think the graph is strongly connected, then by a theorem (moon) it should be hamiltonian.

Comment: But this theorem can only be applied if our graph is a tournament, which is, I think, not the case..

Comment: I believe (?) this is a description of the de Bruijn graphs. You may want to do a quick Google search for more on that topic.